# Applet and JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, file, applet, eventtrigger

Suppose we have an applet on a webpage and JQuery code in the same page, as well. How can we notify JQuery upon an Applet action, for instance a timer in the applet stops and a file system change occurs, and i want to make some process upon this file change in JQuery part as soon as the change occurs. Any suggestions / solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with short article: [Java - Javascript interaction](http://www.raditha.com/java/javascript.php).

And then see [Java-to-Javascript Communication](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html) and
[JavaScript to Java Communication (Scripting)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/js_java.html) for more info.